# Joomla w3 validator

Tags: joomla, xhtml, validation

Im making a website with Joomla and I need to use the following code to show an article.

```
<jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml"  />
<jdoc:include type="message" style="xhtml" />
```

Now when I check my website on w3 validator I get the following 2 errors

```
Line 71, Column 20: there is no attribute "class"
<article class="item-page">

Line 71, Column 31: element "article" undefined
<article class="item-page">
```

They both come from those 2 lines of code but I dont know how to resolve them.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `article` element was introduced in (X)HTML 5.

You appear to be validating against XHTML 1.something.

Either switch to (X)HTML 5 or don't use `article`.

Comment: But woorank sees it as a error so I get a lower SEO score, does google do this to ? how can I change that ?